# Prove $F_{1}^{2}+F_{2}^{2}+\dots+F_{n}^{2}=F_{n}F_{n+1}$ using geometric approach

Tags: summation, fibonacci-numbers

> Prove the identity:  $F_{1}^{2}+F_{2}^{2}+\dots+F_{n}^{2}=F_{n}F_{n+1}$, where $F_i$ denotes a Fibonacci number.

How can I prove it using a geometric approach?

Comment: Always Induction.

Comment: I said geometric approach not algebraic

Comment: Proof by induction is next-to-trivial. Why would you desire a geometric approach and how would you geometrically interpret $F_i$?

Comment: idk the homework said: in a geometry approach

Comment: possible duplicate of [For the Fibonacci numbers, show for all $n$: $F\_1^2+F\_2^2+\dots+F\_n^2=F\_nF\_{n+1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442459/for-the-fibonacci-numbers-show-for-all-n-f-12f-22-dotsf-n2-f-nf-n1)

Answer (score 16):

[image]

The horizontal side length is $F_{n+1}$, in this case $21 + 13=34$. The vertical side is $F_n$, in this case $13 + 8 = 21$. However, the area can also be defined as the sum of the smaller squares.

Comment: sounds good appreciatted!

Comment: That is too cool!