# Fibonacci trick and proving it.

Tags: summation, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to learn Fibonacci tricks and I have one that I can not prove. I know it works because Ive tried it multiple times but I have not a clue how to prove. Here it is:

```
f(0)^2 + f(1)^2 + f(2)^2 + f(3)^2 = f(3)f(3+1)
  0    +   1    +   1    +   4    =   2  *  3
            = 6                          =6
```

Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: Do you mean to prove that $$f(n)^2+f(n+1)^2+f(n+2)^2+f(n+3)^2=f(n+3)f(n+4)?$$

Comment: I think he means to prove that $\sum_{i=0}^n f(i)^2=f(n)f(n+1)$.

Comment: Yes Nishant is correct.

Comment: Do try induction. One (short) line.

Comment: Im sorry but what do you mean by that Andre?

Comment: This was answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442459/for-the-fibonacci-numbers-show-for-all-n-f-12f-22-dotsf-n2-f-nf-n1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basis : ok

Inductive step : Assume $∑_{i=0}^{n}f(i)^2=f(n)f(n+1)$.
$$∑_{i=0}^{n+1}f(i)^2=f(n)f(n+1)+f(n+1)^2$$$$∑_{i=0}^{n+1}f(i)^2=f(n+1)(f(n)+f(n+1))$$$$∑_{i=0}^{n+1}f(i)^2=f(n+1)f(n+2)$$

There is a geometric interpretation:

[image: a]

Comment: +1 for the geometric interpretation (and of course the correct proof).

Answer (score 7):

You've already proven that it works for one example $k=3$. Now write up the general equation
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n F_k^2 = F_n\cdot F_{n+1}
$$
and add $F_{n+1}^2$ on both sides. You get
$$
F_{n+1}^2+ \sum_{k=0}^n F_k^2 =\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} F_k^2 = F_{n+1}^2+ F_n\cdot F_{n+1}=\left(F_{n+1}+ F_n\right)\cdot F_{n+1}
$$
and use $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+ F_n$, the definition of Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Since the base case is true, assume that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(i)^2=f(n)f(n+1)$$
is also true and use this assumption to prove that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}f(i)^2=f(n+1)f(n+2).$$