# Summation of Squares of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Consider the following statement.
 $$\forall n\in\mathbf{N}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}(F_i)^2 = F_nF_{n+1}\right)$$
**Proof.** We prove the statement by recourse to *Strong-Induction*. Assume for an arbitrary natural number $n$ that 
 $$\forall n<k\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}(F_i)^2 = F_kF_{k+1}\right)$$
 Now consider the following Cases.

*Case-1:* $n = 0$,then since $F_0 = 0$ we have $\sum_{i=0}^{0}(F_i)^2 = (F_0)^2 = 0^2 = 0 = 0\cdot F_1 = F_0F_1$.

*Case-2:* $n = 1$, then since $F_1 = 1$ we have $\sum_{i=0}^{0}(F_i)^2 = (F_0)^2+ (F_1)^2 = 0^2 +1^2 = 1 =  1\cdot(1+0) = F_1\cdot F_2$

*Case-3:* $n \ge 2$,then by considering the inductive hypothesis in the particular for $k = n-1$ we see that 
 $$\sum_{j=0}^{n}(F_i)^2 = \sum_{j=0}^{k}(F_i)^2 +(F_n)^2 = F_{n-1}F_n+(F_n)^2$$
 from this point onwards we must show that $F_{n-1}F_n+(F_n)^2 = F_nF_{n+1}$, instead we prove the equivalent statement $(F_n)^2 = F_nF_{n+1}-F_nF_{n-1}$, equivalently we have $F_{n}\cdot(F_{n+1}-F_{n-1})$ from definition of the *Fibonacci* sequence we know that $\forall n\ge 2(F_{n+1} = F_{n}+F_{n-1})$ consequently we have $F_{n} = F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}$ implying that $F_n\cdot(F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}) = F_n\cdot F_n = (F_n)^2$.

Comment: You need to change $j$ to $i$ in the sums.

Comment: This is related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/442459/147357 (which asked for a proof of the fact and didn't provide it's own attempt).

Comment: There are several Q&A's about this identity, but this one specifically asks *"Is the following Proof Correct?"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your proof looks correct apart from some typos: $\forall n<k$ should be $\forall k < n$,
and (as @mathlove
noticed) there is a mix-up between $i$ and $j$ in the indices.

But it can be simplified. In particular you
don't need strong induction since only the inductive hypothesis
for $n-1$ is used to prove the statement for $n$, so “simple induction” is sufficient.

Also $F_{n+1} = F_{n}+F_{n-1}$ holds for $n\ge 1$ and not only
for $n \ge 2$, therefore it is sufficient to consider a single
base case ($n = 0$).

For $n \ge 1$ the inductive step then would be: From the
inductive hypothesis we have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(F_i)^2 = F_{n-1}F_n \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}(F_i)^2 = F_{n-1}F_n+(F_n)^2 = (\underbrace{F_{n-1} + F_n}_{F_{n+1}}) F_n  = F_{n+1}F_n \, .
$$
In the final step, the recurrence relation of the Fibonacci numbers
is used directly, without transformation to an “equivalent statement”.

Answer (score 11):

From the figure below the theorem's proof comes. The rectangle's area is $F_{i}F_{i+1}$.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't address the question asked, which was if the OP's proof was correct. While I think it is often appropriate to supply additional information such as this, you should always state that you are doing so instead of answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

This identity can be seen readily in the Fibonacci mosaic below. Clearly, the area of the overall rectangle, $F_{n+1}\times F_{n}$ is the sum of the areas of the individual squares $F_{k}\times F_{k}$ from $k=1:n$.

[image: Fibonacci Mosiac]

Comment: This does not address the question asked and was posted over an hour after Pet123's post, from which it differs only in arranging the squares in a spiralling pattern instead of building from a corner. What was the point?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for your comment. (1) I didn't see Pet123s at the time I typed this up and (2) my diagram is actually the template for the Fibonacci spiral and is more recognizable and well known. As for why I didn't see the post, I had the page open for over an hour while I falsely pursued the identity $\sum_1^n F_kF_{k-1}=F_n^2,~n \text{ even}$ with another mosaic.