# A Fibonacci conjecture: $\sum_{j=1}^n(\sum_{k=1}^jF_k^2)^3=\left(\sum_{j=1}^nF_j\left(\sum_{k=1}^j F_k^2\right)\right)^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I have been staring at the identity below for over a year now but I haven't found a way around proving it even though I have tested for $n \le 2000$ using my computer.

> $$\sum_{j=1}^{n} \left(\sum_{k=1}^j {F_k}^2 \right)^3 = \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} F_j \left(\sum_{k=1}^j {F_k}^2 \right)\right)^2 $$

I accidentally discovered it while trying to play with the **sum of cubes equalling a square**. I am not a mathematician but I have a passion for it so, I think it is evident I don't have enough mathematical techniques to prove a mathematical claim. I also know I should have made a progress on this identity before I seek help but like I said, I have made all the effort I could but I couldn't crack it at all. I suspect the identity looks similar to that of Nicomanchus theorem which states that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\right)^2 $$

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Verification/Suggestions: [1] Is $F_1 = 1, F_2 = 1, F_n = F_{(n-1)} + F_{(n-2)} ~: ~n \geq 3$? [2] Does ${F_k}^2$ represent $(F_k)^2$? [3] For this problem, It is perfectly valid to use induction to verify that the assertion is always true.  Induction is often easier, and often results in your having formally proven the assertion without intuitively grasping **why** the assertion is true.  Further, induction is also often less elegant than the (alternative) direct approach.  For someone challenged by the problem, my reaction to all of the considerations against induction is **so what**?

Comment: In accordance with [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) you will get a more positive response from mathSE reviewers if you edit your question to show work.  This includes your failed attempts, with reasonable detail, and (perhaps) an attempt to use Induction, if not already included.  Please do not respond with comments.  Analysis/Clarifications belong in the (edited) question.

Comment: Re my first comment, I should confess that I haven't actually attempted Induction against your stated problem.  Therefore, Induction might not readily work.  However, if I was in your situation, Induction would be my first try.

Comment: This, like many other identities of Fibonacci numbers, can be proven the following way: Replace $F_n=\frac{\phi^n-\psi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}$, where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi=-1/\phi$, but these last two values are either not needed at all or only needed at the very end. The rest is just compute the squares or cubes that you have in your identity and sum geometric progressions. You can save some steps by using identities (20) and (21) [here](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/3-3/harris.pdf)

Comment: Note that with using those identities, the one that you want becomes $\sum_{k=1}^{n}F_{k}^3F_{k+1}^3=\frac{1}{4}F_{n+2}^2F_{n+1}^2F_n^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start by known result $F_{1}^{2}+F_{2}^{2}+\dots+F_{n}^{2}=F_{n}F_{n+1}$ (it can be proven simply by induction, see for example  [For the Fibonacci numbers, show for all $n$: $F_1^2+F_2^2+\dots+F_n^2=F_nF_{n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442459)). Using this identity in your statement means you want to show:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n(F_jF_{j+1})^3=\left(\sum_{j=1}^nF_j\left(F_jF_{j+1}\right)\right)^2.
$$
By another known result we have $\sum_{j=1}^nF_j^2 F_{j+1}=\frac{1}{2}F_nF_{n+1}F_{n+2}$, which can be also proven simply by induction. (Note that the induction step amounts to showing $\frac{1}{2}F_nF_{n+1}F_{n+2}+F_{n+1}^2 F_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}F_{n+1}F_{n+2}F_{n+3}$, which is the same $F_n+2F_{n+1}=F_{n+3}$, which follows quickly from recurrence relation).

So using the second result to simplify the right hand side, your statement is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^n(F_jF_{j+1})^3=\left(\frac{1}{2}F_nF_{n+1}F_{n+2}\right)^2.\tag{1}
\end{equation}

This seems to be simple enough to attack by induction on its own.

We can verify it is true for $n=1$ thus establishing the base case. For the induction step, assume (1) is true for $n$, we want to show it holds for $n+1$. Write
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}(F_jF_{j+1})^3=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(F_jF_{j+1})^3+(F_{n+1}F_{n+2})^3=\left(\frac{1}{2}F_nF_{n+1}F_{n+2}\right)^2+(F_{n+1}F_{n+2})^3.
$$
We need to show this is equal $\left(\frac{1}{2}F_{n+1}F_{n+2}F_{n+3}\right)^2$, in other words it remains to show:

$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}F_nF_{n+1}F_{n+2}\right)^2+(F_{n+1}F_{n+2})^3=\left(\frac{1}{2}F_{n+1}F_{n+2}F_{n+3}\right)^2.
$$

Notice both sides have common factor of $F_{n+1}^2F_{n+2}^2$, dividing by it and multiplying by $4$ we are left to show
$$
F_n^2+4F_{n+1}F_{n+2}=F_{n+3}^2\tag{2}.
$$

But this is simple using the recurrence relation few times:
\begin{align}
F_{n+3}^2-F_n^2&=(F_{n+3}-F_n)(F_{n+3}+F_n)\\
&=(F_{n+2}+F_{n+1}-F_n)(F_{n+2}+F_{n+1}+F_n)\\
&=(F_{n+1}+F_n+F_{n+1}-F_n)(F_{n+2}+F_{n+2})\\
&=(2F_{n+1})(2F_{n+2})\\
&=4F_{n+1}F_{n+2}.
\end{align}

Hence the identity required for induction step holds and this completes proof of (1) (and subsequently of the original identity in combination with the previous results).

Comment: A very big thank to all the contributors. After a series of self failed attempts, I always knew there were people out there who could prove it at a glance. I really appreciate you all. Do you think this is worthy of publication by the way?

Comment: @ShuaibLateef You are welcome. As for the publication, I would personally say no, as this this more of an exercise in using basic tools but it does not derive anything new. Perhaps if it would use some novel method of proof or was a long time an open problem, but this is neither (sadly).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.